# Can DataGrip iterate through CSV files?

Tags: csv, datagrip

I'm using DataGrip and need to do multiple queries of the following format:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '01345' AND date = '01-01-2020'
```

For each query, the id and date are different. I have a CSV file with many rows, each row containing a different id and date. Is there a way to get DataGrip to iterate through the CSV file and execute all required queries, and save each output as a CSV file (all outputs combined as a single CSV file would also suffice)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one step solution.
But here what I would do:

1. Import CSV file into a table in a temporary in-memory database, e.g. H2
2. Write your custom extractor, see [examples](https://gist.github.com/moscas/793e441b12872b8339a1471966343439#file-csv-toonerow-groovy-csv-groovy) by @moscas

Additionally, see DataGrip blog posts about export and extractors:

- [Export data in any way with intellij based ides](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2017/11/08/export-data-in-any-way-with-intellij-based-ides/)
- [Data extractors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/data-extractors.html)
- [What objects functions are available for custom data extractors](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205993979-What-objects-functions-are-available-for-custom-data-extractors-)